# how can I create widget with nodejs - add script to webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm looking ways to create nodejs widget for websites, where users will implement script tag on webpage and widget will be loaded?

hoping to get guidance, idea to start small widget.

Thanx for help in advance

Comment: nodejs is  a server side language, it is not intended to be executed in the browser

Comment: for widgets you can use a templating engine or you can an html file(which tahs the widget) and load it when you want or use a frontend framework. but a I dont get what you mean by a nodejs widget